# Initialse objects with ngModel (Ionic)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

probably an easy one but can't quite figure it out. I have successfully posted a JSON object to my API but feel like it could be a bit cleaner. I have a User object with a nested address object inside. It looks like this:

```
{
  "forename": "string",
  "surname": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "dob": "2018-02-20T13:26:54.476Z",
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "string",
    "addressLine2": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "postalCode": "string",
  },
  "password": "string"
}
```

I have these 2 objects:

User.ts

```
export class User {
    Forename : string;
    Surname : string;
    Email : string;
    // DOB : DateTime;
    Address : Address;
    Password : string;
    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
   }
}
```

And, Address.ts:

```
export class Address {
    AddressLine1 : string;
    AddressLine2 : string;
    City : string;
    PostalCode : string;
    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
   }
}
```

The way I am creating the object to POST is via the ngModel in my HTML which looks like this (just an example, not the full code):

SignUp.html:

```
<ion-item>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.Forename" id='txtFname' placeholder="First Name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.Surname" id='txtLname' placeholder="Last Name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

And for the address:

```
<ion-item>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.Address.AddressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.Address.AddressLine2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

In my signup.ts I am instantiating my object by first initializing every field and then posting to my api. This doesnt feel right to me although it is the only way I can get this to work. This method doesn't use the defined Address.ts and User.ts shown above.

SignUp.ts

```
newUser : User = { Forename: '', Surname: '', Email: '',  
  Address: {AddressLine1: '', AddressLine2: '', City: '', PostalCode: ''},
  Password: ''};
```

If someone could show me a cleaner method than the one I have implemented in the SignUp.ts (or SignUp.html if that isn't correct either), i'm happy to take any and all advice. Im relatively new to this.

Thanks in advance.

PS - I also can't figure out how to initialize the DOB field with the above method (although that is not a major concern for now).

Answer (score 0):

A good way deal with forms is to use @angular/forms.
It will give you a nice structure and allow you to use Validators more easily.

[Ionic Forms Link implementing @angular/forms](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/)

[Angular Documentation about Reactive Forms for advanced features](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)